# Dyanmic structure error, pointers conversion

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-allocation

i get this error at the constructor of my struct. why do i get it sincei work only with * pointers not **.

Error:

```
\ListStruc.cpp:26:25: error: cannot convert 'int**' to 'int*' in assignment
```

struct.h

```
struct Arr{

    int days;
    int *M;
};
typedef Arr* Array;
```

struct.cpp

```
void constr(Array &o){
    //Construct of 1*31 Matrix
    o=new Arr;
    o->days = days;
    o->M = new int*[o->days];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `M` is an `int*`, the correct initialization would be:

```
o->M = new int[o->days];
```

Comment: thanks >.>
how can i init the array with objects of a class i get error int cant be converted to Expre, expe beeing my class.

Comment: @BogdanMaier I literally didn't understand anything you just said.

Comment: i fixed the error. Now i`m looking forward to make that array, an array of class objects were do i have to declare in the constructor/header that or how should i do it since classes arent types and i have no clue how should i do that?

Comment: @BogdanMaier you could ask another question. be sure to include new code that you're trying to write. btw classes are types. the only difference between struct and class is class members are private by default.

Comment: @BogdanMaier maybe you should ask a new question with the code you have now and what you want to achieve.